# Insertion Sort program in C giving weird result

Tags: c, sorting

This program is giving unexpected results. I think there is a problem in returning the array to the main().

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *isort(int array[], int size)
{
    int i, j, key;
    for (j = 1; j < size; j++) {
        array[j] = key;
        i = j - 1;
        while (i > 0 && array[i] > key) {
            array[i + 1] = array[i];
            i--;
        }
        array[i + 1] = key;
    }
    return array;
}   

main()
{
    int array[100], size, i, *result;

    printf("\nSIZE: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("\nARRAY: ");

    for (i=0; i<size ; i++)
        scanf("%d\t", &array[i]);

    result = isort(array, size);

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Your claim of unexpected results implies there are *expected* results What are they, and how are they different than what you're getting? (bonus points for postulating the reason for the differences).

Comment: Show us the test input and the expected result; show us the result you actually get. Do it with a small value of `size`, for the sake of our sanity.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you start off wrong with `main(){`. That should be `int main ( void ) {`

Comment: I think you don't need to return array, you are sorting in-place, change will be reflect at calling place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One mistake in assignment is severe! Correct it as:

```
array[j] = key; // it is undefined to assign with an uninitialized variable
```

Should be:

```
key = array[j];
```

Edit: One more logical mistake is that you don't sort value at index `0`, in inner loop:

```
while (i > 0 && array[i] > key)
```

should be:

```
while (i >= 0 && array[i] > key) // note you are using a[i + 1] = a[1]
//        ^^                     // but not i - 1
```

Additionally,

You can remove `\t` in the format string of `scanf` when you scan array values. Just use `scanf("%d", &array[i]);`. If you use `\t` in `scanf` format string, it will consume any number of white spaces till you don't enter a non-whitespace character.

The manual of  [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) says,

> A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see
>   `isspace(3)`). This directive matches any amount of white space,
>   including none, in the input.

One more thing is you don't need to return array address from the sorting function because you are passing address so the changes done by the sort function will be reflected in `main`. Although this is not a mistake. Point is you were printing array via `array[i]`  instead `result[i]`.

If you correct the above mistakes, then your code should run fine: check here @[codepad](http://codepad.org/hmb7MCjd) (I changed `main()` to int main() and return `0` but  that is a different matter).

Comment: Side note: `%d` also by itself consumes any whitespace. In otherwords `" %d"` and `"%d"` are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your problems could be solved by stepping through the program using a debugger. The earlier you learn to use a debugger the better -- it will help you over and over again.

For example, if you paused this program at the start of the `for()` loop, and stepped through, you could watch what happens at:

```
 array[j] = key;
```

Assuming you understand the algorithm, you will be expecting `key` to become the 2nd value in your input list. You will be surprised to see that `key` does not change from its initial value (either 0 or an arbitrary number, depending on your C environment), and that `array[j]` changes instead. And then you will realise your mistake:

```
 key = array[j];
```

Keep stepping through your program with the debugger, and you will probably find other issues.

---

You mention that you "think there is a problem in returning the array to the main()".

In fact your `iSort()` function always returns the same array that was passed to it. `int *` and `int[]` are both pointers to int.

So `iSort()`:

- accepts a pointer to the start of an array
- modifies the contents of that array
- returns the same pointer

Your `main`:

- creates and populates `array`
- passes `array` to `iSort()`
- gets `result` returned by `iSort()`
- ignores `result` and prints `array`

.. but since `result` and `array` are equal -- both pointers to the start of the same array, it doesn't matter.

There is no reason (other than a style choice) why `iSort()` couldn't be a void function.

Since you ignore `result` there's no reason for it to exist. Just call `iSort()` by itself:

```
iSort(array, size);
```

Some people like to provide an indication that they're deliberately ignoring the result of a function call:

```
(void) iSort(array, size);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int *isort(int array[], int size)
{

int i, j, key;

       for (j = 1; j < size; j++) {

           key = array[j] ;

           i = j - 1;

             while ((array[i] > key) && (i >= 0) ) {

               array[i + 1] = array[i];

                 i--;

         }

         array[i + 1] = key;

     }

    return array;

 }


int main()

{

    int array[100], size, i, *result;

    printf("\nSIZE: ");

    scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("\nARRAY: ");

    for (i=0; i<size ; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);

    result = isort(array, size);

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Read   Shahbaz's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877674/insertion-sort-program-in-c-giving-weird-result/21879035#comment33126048_21878252)

Answer (score -3):

```
int *isort(int array[], int size)
{
    int i, j, tmp;
    for (j = 1; j < size; j++) {
        i = j ;
        while (i > 0 && array[i-1] > array[i]) {
            tmp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i - 1];
                array[i - 1] = tmp;
                i--;  
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Just giving some working code doesn't have any didactic value. If anything, it would just make people inclined to posting their questions on SO and expecting working code in return for no effort.